# Putting edit text input into a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, matlab-guide

I'm a beginner. I want to ask, how to put edit text to matrix? For example, I have 30 edit text that will fill by number 0 - 1. I want to make matrix `x(1,1)`,....`x(1,30)` from the input of edit text.

I have tried this code :

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
% str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double

x(1, 1) = str2double(get(hObject,'string'))
```

till....

```
function edit30_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject handle to edit30 (see GCBO)
% eventdata reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit30 as text
% str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit30 as a double

x(1, 30) = str2double(get(hObject,'string'))
```

but, the command window show like this...

```
x =

     1

x =

     0 0

x =

     0 0 0

x =

         0 0 0 0.2500

x =

         0 0 0 0 0.5000

x =

     0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but actually I want the result is matrix, like

```
1 0 0 0.25 0.5 0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is function scope. Each callback function defines `x` in its own scope, so when the function ends (displaying the `x` value in console) the `x` will gone.

One way is to pass the `x` variable between functions using `handles` structure. Just use `handles.x` instead of `x`. I would also recommend to initialize this matrix as `handles.x = zeros(1,30);` at GUI initialization.

Comment: oke..thanks for your answer.
I have to try like that, but it doesn't work.
can you explain me more detail about the coding?
I really really have no idea about that.
is it possible to putting edit text input in matrix?